# What does this condition mean in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following condition in a `WHERE` clause:

```
AND flag&(2+4+1048576+16777216)=0
```

What does the above mean? The Flag field data-type is `Integer`.

Comment: it's a bit mask. note that the numbers being added are all powers-of-two. `&` is the bit-wise AND operator.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx

Comment: Flag=266400 is returned. How above condition makes it possible? Thanks

Comment: 266400 = 0b1000001000010100000; 
2+4+1048576+16777216 = 0b1000100000000000000000110.  Since none of the 1-bits are aligned, the `&` of the two values is 0, and the condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This where clause is taking advantage of binary arithmetic,
this is indicated by the bitwise ('&') anding operator.

The flag's decimal value of 266400 is represented in binary as 0b1000001000010100000.

The integer literals added together have a decimal value of 17825798.
The binary representation is 0b1000100000000000000000110.

By Adding these binary values together gives:

```
      0b1000001000010100000  <- flags binary value
0b1000100000000000000000110  <- literals binary value
===========================
0b0000000000000000000000000  <- '&' operator results
```

Since no column has both bits set to 1, the overall result is 0.

So the where clause succeeds because flag&(2+4+1048576_16777216) = 0, or 0 = 0, which is true.

Answer (score 0):

This code are looking for some bits in the field flag doesn't set at 1.

Each value has a binary representation:

```
2        = 0000000000000000000000010
4        = 0000000000000000000000100
1048576  = 0000100000000000000000000
16777216 = 1000000000000000000000000
------------------------------------ +
17825798 = 1000100000000000000000110
```

I only have ORACLE here, so please, let me use ORACLE syntax for explain it (you can use & operator instead):

If you check a flag with any of those values, you will always recieve a non-zero response.

Example:

```
SELECT BITAND( 2, 17825798 ) FROM DUAL;

return 2

SELECT BITAND( 2+4, 17825798 ) FROM DUAL;

return 6
```

If you check with another random bit like...

```
SELECT BITAND( 2+1, 17825798 ) FROM DUAL;

return 2

SELECT BITAND( 2+16, 17825798 ) FROM DUAL;

return 2
```

Because you only check for some bits in your field flag.

So, if the bitwise operator return 0, any bit in 17825798 mask is set at 1.